# How to draw multiple shapes on JComponent or Jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, draw

I'm trying to build **Paint** app and I doing something wrong in DrawingArea class.
The problem is when I try to draw second shape , the first shape or figure is auto deleting so I need to some idea about how to solve this.All answers acceptable.
THANKS FOR HELP.

There is part of ***DrawingArea.class*** codes :

```
    @Override // GETTING FIRST (STARTING) COORDINATE WHEN THE MOUSE PRESSED
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        oldX = e.getX();
        oldY = e.getY();
        repaint();

    }

    @Override // GETTING RELEASED COORDINATE TO DRAW LINE.
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        lastX = e.getX();
        lastY = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        clickedX = true;
        COUNT = e.getClickCount();
    }

    // GETTING COORDINATE TO DRAW FILLEDRECT,FILLEDOVAL,OVAL,RECT.
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        draggedX = e.getX();
        draggedY = e.getY();
        repaint();
        width = Math.abs(oldX - draggedX);
        height = Math.abs(oldY - draggedY);
        x = Math.min(draggedX, oldX);
        y = Math.min(draggedY, oldY);

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    // CLEAR THE ALL SHAPES DRAWED ON DRAW AREA.
    public void clear() {
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, (int) this.getWidth() + 55, (int) this.getHeight() + 55);
        super.repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image == null) {
            image = new BufferedImage((int) this.getWidth(), (int) this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            clear();
        }

        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        g2.dispose();

        g.setColor(initialColor);
        if (shape == Shapers.PENCIL) {
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            g.fillOval(draggedX, draggedY, thickness, thickness);

        } else if (shape == Shapers.OVAL) {
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            g.drawOval(oldX, oldY, draggedX, draggedX);

        } else if (shape == Shapers.FILLEDOVAL) {
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            g.fillOval(oldX, oldY, draggedX, draggedY);

        } else if (shape == Shapers.RECT) {
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);

        } else if (shape == Shapers.FILLEDRECT) {
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

        } else if (shape == Shapers.LINE) {
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            g.drawLine(oldX, oldY, draggedX, draggedY);
            oldX = draggedX;
            oldY = draggedY;

        } else if (shape == Shapers.ERASER) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(draggedX, draggedY, thickness, thickness);

        } else if (shape == Shapers.TEXT) {
            if (clickedX == true || COUNT == 2) {
                String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write Your Text Here : ");
                g.setFont(myFont);
                g.setColor(currentColor);
                if (str != null) {
                    g.drawString(str, oldX, oldY);
                    COUNT = 0;

                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            COUNT = 0;
            return;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You need to draw on a (Buffered)Image, and just display the image in your paintComponent method. See PaintArea for an example:https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/PaintArea.java

Comment: @ControlAltDel Excuse me please but I cannot understand why more time used buffered image? For all shapes we need to create new buffered image or how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either:

1. Store shapes to be painted in a List and then in the paintComponent() method you paint all the shapes in the List, or
2. Paint your shapes to a BufferedImage and then just paint the BufferedImage

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both approaches and use the approach that best meets your requirement.

Comment: Awesome method, I'm so confused can u show me a simple example on my codes please?

Comment: SO is not a code generation machine. camickr linked to two complete examples using different approaches. Try adapting one of them to your code then get back to us if you have a *specific* question.

Comment: Thank u Andrew Thompson. I tried to add shapes to ArrayList but when I dragging the mouse printing multiple shapes(nested, small to big).

Comment: And drawing with BufferedImage result also print unwanted multiple shapes (nested, small to big).

Comment: @CoderACJHP, do you see unwanted multiple shapes when you execute the code found in the link? You should only be saving the shape on the mouseReleased event.

Comment: @camickr Thank you for your interest.You are right but if I use mouseReleased for drawing I cannot see the shape during draw.Sorry for my bad Eng :)

Comment: @CoderACJHP, Again, the code in the link draws the shape as the mouse is dragged and then saves the shape on the mouse released. You have been given a working example. Study the code and modify your example as required.

Comment: Thank u so much :) Finally I solved it with ArrayList method.