# I am not sure how calling the paint function works in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

So literally just today I started messing around with Java swing and I got the idea to try and make a tic tac toe game from scratch, but I cant seem to get the hang of the paint function, when and how is it called, in example from an external file. This is what I mean:
The main file:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class probvam extends Canvas {
public static void Game(){
    Field f = new Field();
    f.setField(0, 0, 560/3, 560/3);
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.add(f);
    window.setTitle("zvunqt mi po iphona");
    window.setSize(560, 560);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Game();

}
}
```

The file I am trying to draw graphics from:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Field extends Canvas{
int width, height, x, y;

public void setField(int w, int h, int x, int y){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

}
```

How can I call the paint function?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: *You* normally don't call the paint function; the GUI library does it for you when needed.

Comment: 1) Don't extend Canvas, that is an AWT component. In Swing you extend JPanel (or JComponent). Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples. 2) Swing will generally repaint the component automatically when required. However, if you change a property of your custom class that affects painting then your class should invoke the repaint() method.

Comment: There is **much** to learn.   So do what @camickr said.

Comment: Thank you guys after reading for a bit I got a hang of it but now I have another problem, when I add multiple instances of the second class to the frame, my old rectangles go away, how do I keep previously written graphics on the screen

Comment: Only one JPanel does the painting. The classes with the rectangle information should be non-GUI, non-component classes that are held and displayed by the drawing JPanel, often by iterating through a collection, such as an ArrayList, in a for loop, for instance as per @camickr's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660946/how-to-draw-multiple-shapes-on-jcomponent-or-jpanel).

Comment: Go and read [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html).  Your "previous" rectangles are disappearing because the panels are been laid on top of each other.  This is not how you should be doing it, see Hovercraft's previous comment

Comment: *"but now I have another problem"* So ask a new question on a new question thread.